# Is it better to use look-behind or capture groups?

Tags: php, regex

I'm not sure if one of these is 'better' then the other, and why it would be, but I've got an original string that looks like this:

```
$string = '/random_length_user/file.php';
```

Now, there are two ways to match it, the first, using my new friend, the look-behind, and the 2nd, without:

```
preg_match("%(?<=^/)([^/]*)%", $string, $capture);
preg_match("%^/([^/]*)%", $string, $capture);
```

They return, in order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => random_length_user
)
Array
(
    [0] => /random_length_user
    [1] => random_length_user
)
```

Essentially I get the result I want in $capture[0] using look-behind, and in $capture[1] without. Now the question is ...  is there a reason to prefer one of these methods over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the lookbehind approach is not as flexible; it falls down when you start dealing with variable-length matches.  For example, suppose you wanted to extract the file name in your example, and you didn't know the name of the directory.  The capturing-group technique still works fine:

```
preg_match("%^/\w+/([^/]*)%", '/random_length_user/file.php');

Array
(
    [0] => /random_length_user/file.php
    [1] => file.php
)
```

...but the lookbehind approach doesn't, because lookbehind expressions can only match a fixed number of characters.  However, there's an even better alternative: `\K`, the MATCH POINT RESET operator.  Wherever you put it, the regex engine pretends the match really started there.  So you get the same result as you would with a lookbehind, without the fixed-length limitation:

```
preg_match('%^/\w+/\K[^/]+$%', '/random_length_user/file.php');

Array
(
    [0] => file.php
)
```

As far as I know, this feature is only available in Perl 5.10+ and in tools (like PHP's `preg_` functions) that are powered by the PCRE library.  For the PCRE reference, see [the manpage](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and search (F3) for `\K`.

Answer (score 3):

It probably doesn't make a difference with `preg_match`, but it will matter when using `preg_replace`, as it affects what will be replaced.

It might also be an issue when you do a global match, because the capturing group will consume characters, while the lookarounds will not

Trivial example:

- `/(?<=a)a/g` with `'aaaa'` gives `Array('a', 'a', 'a')`
- `/(a)a/g` with `'aaaa'` gives `Array('aa', 'aa')`